# Parse name components from the form Last,First,Middle,Suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, ssms

Right now, I have a full name column in which full names do not have a normalized form.  The form generally follows the Last,First Middle,Suffix but it's not vanilla for all rows.  Some example forms include:

- Last,First Middle,Suffix
- Last,First Middle Suffix
- Last,First,Suffix
- Last,First Suffix
- Last,First Middle
- Last,First

Desired results are to have each component in it's own column, with NULL for components that do not exist.  Here are some examples of desired results.

```
FULLNAME                    FIRSTNAME  MIDDLENAME LASTNAME  SUFFIX
Johnson,John Johnny,Jr.     John       Johnny     Johnson   Jr
Anderson,Andrew A, Sr.      Andrew     A          Anderson  Sr
Smith,Smitty Jr.            Smitty     NULL       Smith     Jr
Abegnale,Frank              Frank      NULL       Abegnale  NULL
Henry,King III              King       NULL       Henry     III
Garcia,Jerome John          Jerome     John       Garcia    NULL
```

The current solution I have in place is this:

```
SELECT
FullName
,SUBSTRING(FullNM, 1, CHARINDEX(',', FullNM) - 1) AS LastName
,CASE
      WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(FullNM, CHARINDEX(',',FullNM)+ 1,99)) - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(FullNM, CHARINDEX(',',FullNM)+ 1,99), ' ', '')) > 0
      THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(FullNM, LEN(FullNM) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullNM))+1, 99), '.', '')
      ELSE NULL
    END AS MiddleName
,CASE
      WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(FullNM, CHARINDEX(',',FullNM) + 1, 99)) - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(FullNM, CHARINDEX(',',FullNM)+ 1, 99), ' ', '')) > 0
      THEN SUBSTRING(FullNM, CHARINDEX(',',FullNM) + 1, (LEN(SUBSTRING(FullNM, CHARINDEX(',',FullNM)+ 1, 99)) - LEN(SUBSTRING(FullNM, LEN(FullNM) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullNM)) + 1, 99))))
      ELSE SUBSTRING(FullNM,CHARINDEX(',',FullNM) + 1, 99)
    END AS FirstNM
FROM MyTable
```

Unfortunately, I just can't figure out a good way to format the suffix, especially in the cases where there is no middle name.  With the current code, if there is a suffix, it gets added as a MiddleNM.

Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: `Henry,King III`  and `Garcia,Jerome John` are  syntactically equal. You need some extra source to tell the difference you want as the output.

Comment: Do you have a table of suffixes?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution. It is using XQuery to tokenize the **FullName** column.

As Gordon mentioned, you may need to extend your list of legit suffixes.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FullName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (FullName) VALUES
('Johnson,John Johnny,Jr.'),
('Anderson,Andrew A, Sr.'),    
('Smith,Smitty Jr.'),  
('Abegnale,Frank'),        
('Henry,King III'),          
('Garcia,Jerome John');

DECLARE @suffix TABLE (suffix VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @suffix (suffix) VALUES
('Jr.'), ('III'), ('Sr.');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT * 
      , TRY_CAST('<root><x><![CDATA[' + 
            REPLACE(FullName + SPACE(1) COLLATE Czech_BIN2, @separator, ']]></x><x><![CDATA[') + 
         ']]></x></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
   FROM @tbl
), cte AS
(
SELECT rs.*, x.pos, x.size
    , LEFT(c.value('(x[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), pos - 1) AS FirstName
    , c.value('(x[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS LastName
    , TRIM(RIGHT(c.value('(x[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), IIF((size - pos) < 0, 0, size-pos+1))) AS MiddleName
    , TRIM(COALESCE(c.value('(x[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
        , RIGHT(c.value('(x[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'), IIF((size - pos) < 0, 0, size-pos+1)))) AS Suffix
FROM rs CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(SPACE(1), c.value('(x[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'))
        , LEN(c.value('(x[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'))) AS x(pos, size)
)
SELECT ID, FullName, cte.FirstName
    , IIF(MiddleName IN (SELECT Suffix FROM @suffix, '', cte.MiddleName) AS MiddleName
    , cte.LastName
    , IIF(cte.Suffix NOT IN (SELECT Suffix FROM @suffix), '', cte.Suffix) AS Suffix
FROM cte;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
| ID |        FullName         | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Suffix |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1 | Johnson,John Johnny,Jr. | John      | Johnny     | Johnson  | Jr.    |
|  2 | Anderson,Andrew A, Sr.  | Andrew    | A          | Anderson | Sr.    |
|  3 | Smith,Smitty Jr.        | Smitty    |            | Smith    | Jr.    |
|  4 | Abegnale,Frank          | Frank     |            | Abegnale |        |
|  5 | Henry,King III          | King      |            | Henry    | III    |
|  6 | Garcia,Jerome John      | Jerome    | John       | Garcia   |        |
+----+-------------------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I run into an error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."  I know that I could introduce a fake "space".  Do you have any solutions without using XML.  I want this to be more easily understood, especially by those who may not have a lot of SQL experience.

Comment: @EthanT, (1) please edit your original question, and add the **DDL and sample data population** section. (2) I prefer to use XML and XQuery for easy string tokenization.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of brain ache and a Sql server bug later, here is one possible solution you can try.

It's a bit on the verbose side and, as suggested, does require you to know in advance what the possible suffixes are.

```
with 
    num as (select top(30) Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) n from sys.messages),
    parts as (
        select top(1000) n.Fullname, w.n, /*sql server optimizer issue workaround*/
            IsNull(Iif( CharIndex(',',name1)=0 and CharIndex(' ',name1)=0 ,name1,null),
            Iif( CharIndex(',',name2)=0 and CharIndex(' ',name2)=0 ,name2,null)) part
        from Names n
        cross apply (
            select num.n, Substring(n.Fullname, num.n, CharIndex(',', n.Fullname + ',', num.n) - num.n) name1, 
                Substring(n.Fullname, num.n, CharIndex(' ', n.Fullname + ' ', num.n) - num.n) name2
            from num
            where num.n<DataLength(n.Fullname) and Substring(',' + n.Fullname, num.n, 1) in (',', ' ')
        )w
)
select Fullname, 
    Max(FirstName) firstName, 
    Max(Iif(MiddleName=FirstName or MiddleName=Lastname,null,MiddleName))MiddleName, 
    Max(Lastname) LastName, 
    Max(Suffix) Suffix
from (
    select Fullname,
        case when Lag(n) over(partition by Fullname order by n)=Min(n) over(partition by Fullname) then part end FirstName,
        case when Lead(n) over(partition by Fullname order by n)=Max(n) over(partition by Fullname) and Suffix is null 
            or n=Max(n) over(partition by Fullname) and Suffix is null then part end MiddleName,
        case when n=Min(n) over(partition by Fullname) then part end Lastname,
        case when n=Max(n) over(partition by Fullname) and Suffix is not null then part end Suffix
    from parts p
    left join Suffixes s on s.Suffix=p.part
    where p.part !=''
)x
group by Fullname
order by Fullname
```

See this [working fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01055b/1)